# Criteria (NOT TOOLS) to check what version of python a piece of code is written for?

Tags: python, version, compatibility

One finds many small programs or sample code on the Internet, which do no not necessarily specify in which context they were written (shebang), and do not necessarily use obvious things as print statements.

They may crash with some or some other version of python, but this may not be due to fundamental incompatibilities but just due to missing libraries which might be hard to find.

There are some tools as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804538/tool-to-determine-what-lowest-version-of-python-required) but the question here is: "What would be good criteria to decide if a code is compatible with either version of python ?"

There are at least :

- The presence of the shebang (But it is often not present)
- Print statements (without parenthesis) are from python2 or before (But you do not always have them, especially in GUI programs)
- Integer division (//) is from python 3 and later (But not all programs compute integer divisions)

What else ?

@Mureinik, @JJJ, @Bear Brown, @Tempux, please remove duplicate flag.

Comment: Kind of a subjective one, but I'd probably look at how the print statements are formatted.

Comment: The same program may run in all Python versions because there are more common things and differences between the versions. So just run the program under the version you want and you will get an answer yourself.

Comment: Look for a shebang. Or a comment. Or the person who wrote it.

Comment: I got this on review and am voting leave closed. Follow the link to the tool and read the code and there's your answer.

Comment: Sending readers to a piece of code is not very user friendly. Especially since people looking for pieces of code might quite often NOT be experienced programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a python script will include a shebang on the first line something like: `#!/usr/bin python` and/or comments telling you the minimum, (and possibly maximum), version that it will work with.

Other clues:

```
print Something  # Python 2 Only
print(Something)  # Python 3 Mostly

from __future__ import print_function # As first active code

print(Something)  # Now works for both
```

Of course and well written code will either be compatible with many versions or specifically check for the version*s* that it requires.

If libraries are missing then the error messages are really clear but for the most part python code tends to "just run"™ so the real solution is to try the code with the version*s* of python that you have to hand.

Comment: I've also see some libraries check `sys.version_info` and raise a `RuntimeError` in case the wrong Python version was used (usually in `__init__.py`).

Comment: Good point @Coal_ however those tend to be in well written libraries rather than small utilities & code snippets found on-line as per the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer from official documentation : [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

I am assuming that you have an IDE for **Python 3.x** where you can try that piece of code.
As stated by Steve, You can differentiate by using the `print` function of python(x).

```
print "hello world"
```

So, if there is print statement(like above) in the code you will get:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.
```

Thus, that piece of code was for **2.x python** .

Comment: Yes, the difference between the print statement in python 2 and the print function in python 3 escaped me. However, and it is the reason why i specified "small programs" or "sample codes", they may not necessarilly have shebang or print instructions (especially for GUI code)

Comment: You can add your print() statemement and then run it.Solved?

Comment: You can go through the Official Doc

Comment: Well, I'm looking for quick tricks. The documentation is interresting, for sure, but for the most, it will give me thinks that work differently, but not necessarily look different.

Comment: There are no such 'quick tricks' in any language.You should go in depth and practice accordingly.Still If you have less time then you can go for `print()` in the code.

Comment: For sure there are. print is one. The formatting system and shebang are others. why wouldn't there be any others ?